# 301 Redirect: remove middle folder structure but preserve end file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Wordpress installation.

Indexed Files = http://www.mydomain.com/blog/somecontent

New structure = http://www.mydomain.com/somecontent

Need to remove the /blog/ and 301 redirect to /somecontent across 1000 pages.

Any help would be appreciated as google has indexed previous /blog/ site structure and now giving 404's on new url's.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First thing you must do is to go to Wordpress settings and change WP install path to `/somecontent` then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory **above your regular WP stuff**:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: @anubhava I want to do something similar, but my urls also contain different dates, such as:
'/blog/2017/04'
'/blog/2009/05'

how would I remove the /blog and the dates using .htaccess to 301 rewrite

Comment: Use: `RewriteRule ^blog/\d+/\d+/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have mod_rewrite enabled, you might try something similar to

```
RewriteRule ^blog/somecontent/(.*)$ http://example.com/somecontent/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this assume the same structure under both folders.